# create session specific data

Tags: php, session

Good afternoon, everybody.
I'm here with a doubt.

Already have an active session, and I have to create another session. with more data.

More This new session is getting empty and the data is going to the first session.

Anyone know how to add data in the session specified by name.

I would be very grateful for the help.

Comment: It would help if you could explain why do you want to have the second session.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple sessions active at the same time. However a session is just an associative array, so you can create multiple namespaces inside using different keys. For example

```
$_SESSION['one'] = $foo;
$_SESSION['two'] = $bar;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can specify separate sessions using session_name(). Another thing you can do is read the actual session files if you have access to them on the file system. Variables and data are all there in plain text.

But all this sounds very sloppy to me and I can't imagine why you would need to do it this way. Provide more information about what you're trying to accomplish and maybe we can help you find a more straightforward way of achieving it.

Comment: Yes I did with session_name, more  it sends data to my first session.

Comment: One example, social site has only 10 cookies on the first page.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you could just use a local variable to store the data as you're switching sessions.

Comment: First mind thank you for your attention. I'm not editing the session. And yes I want to create another session with new data. And even creates a new session id. More is blank, no data. The data goes all the first session ever created.

Comment: I'm afraid I no longer understand what you're trying to accomplish.